# needed ER diagram for following scenario

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

a supplier located in only one city supplies various parts for the projects to different companies located in various cities.Draw ER diagram for this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a homework question? You might want to check out the guidelines: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.  Basically try to do it yourself first and ask specific questions about what problems you have, and you might get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supplier <-N--located in--1-> City

Supplier <-1--delivers parts to--N-> Company

Company <-N--located in--1-> City

if one company can be located in various cities
you'll need
Company <-1--N-> Company2City <-N---1-> City